# How to put an update in a API function

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

as a rule, it's better to hide the single-row fetches inside a function, so instead of:

```
BEGIN 
   SELECT name
   INTO l_name   
     FROM mytable    
    WHERE primary_key = id_primary_key;
```

it would be better to develop a

```
PACKAGE mypackage
IS 
   FUNCTION fnc_name (id_primary_key IN mytable.primary_key%TYPE) 
      RETURN mytable.name%TYPE;
```

and executing

```
BEGIN 
   l_name := mypackage.fnc_name (id_primary_key);
```

But what about updating?
I mean, if I decide to develop the same solution for updating but in that case every time I need to update only few columns of the table, how would you develop such an API?

Oracle version 10g

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You are starting to develop a "table API" or "TAPI".  These are problematic, for the reason you have mentioned: if the TAPI's update procedure updates all 20 columns of the table from 20 parameters, but in a particular case you only need to update 3 columns, how should you call it?  One way is to simply have to pass all 20 values even though you are not changing most of them.  Another is to give each parameter a "funny" default like `CHR(0)` and have the API update be like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column1 = CASE WHEN p_column1 = CHR(0) THEN column1 ELSE p_column1 END,
...
```

A different (I'd say better) approach is the "Transaction API" or XAPI.  Here you build a separate procedure for each business transaction that might need to update the table.  For example:

```
PROCEDURE terminate_employee
   ( p_empid INTEGER
   , p_termination_date DATE
   , p_termination_reason VARCHAR2
   );
```

This procedure will use a simple SQL update statement to update the 3 columns that need to be updated when terminating an employee.

Some would say SQL **is** an API to the database!

Comment: "As a rule, it's better to hide the single-row fetches inside a function"; Who says? Why? IMHO I am perfectly happy with a single table fetches in-line with the rest of the code, they are simple statements. What I want to hide behind function boundaries are long complicated queries and/or highly involved processing.

Comment: @Belayer Well, not me!